# Zend Framework 2, MVC pattern and View Helpers disussion

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework2, zend-view, view-helpers

What's sence have use view Helpers which they can see business logic if the goal of the MVC pattern is separate the view of the business logic?

When I use the View Helper, it breaks the separation between both terms, does this mean that the view helpers can't use model classes?
Or that the view helpers nonly can use service locator for obtains model classes?

Answer (score 0):

The "V" part of MVC can has logic as far as its only handle how view displayed, not how to manage data.